# Is using an array as a conditional expression valid in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have this code:

```
int main()
{
    char buffer[10];
    if( buffer ) {
       return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

which Visual C++ 10 interprets like this: `buffer` decays to a pointer, then a pointer is compared against null. When this is compiled with /O2 the check gets eliminated and the code gets equivalent to just `return 1;`.

Is the code above valid? Does Visual C++ compile it right (I mean the decaying part, not the optimization)?

Comment: The elision optimization, at least, seems completely sensible to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the conversion from an array type to `bool` is well-defined by the standard conversions. Quoting C++11, 4/1 (with the relevant conversions highlighted):

> A standard conversion sequence is a sequence of standard conversions in the following
>   order:
>
> — Zero or one conversion from the following set: lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, **array-to-pointer conversion**,
>   and function-to-pointer conversion.
>
> — Zero or one conversion from the following set: integral promotions, floating point promotion, integral
>   conversions, floating point conversions, floating-integral conversions, pointer conversions, pointer to
>   member conversions, and **boolean conversions**.
>
> — Zero or one qualification conversion.
>
> A standard conversion sequence will be applied to an expression if necessary to convert it to a required
>   destination type.

Answer (score 7):

C++11, 6.4/4:

> The value of a condition that is an expression is the value of the
>   expression, contextually converted to bool for statements other than
>   switch; if that conversion is ill-formed, the program is ill-formed.

So the standard says that the compiler has to perform any implicit conversions at its disposal to convert the array to a boolean. Decaying the array to pointer and converting the pointer to boolean with a test against against equality to null is one way to do that, so yes the program is well-defined and yes it does produce the correct result -- obviously, since the array is allocated on the stack, the pointer it decays to can never be equal to the null pointer.

**Update:** As to *why* this chain of two conversions is followed:

C++11, 4.2/1:

> An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown bound
>   of T” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T”. The result
>   is a pointer to the first element of the array.

So, the only legal conversion from an array type is to a pointer to element type. There is no choice in the first step.

C++11, 4.12/1:

> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, **pointer**, or pointer
>   to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type `bool`. A zero
>   value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted
>   to `false`; any other value is converted to `true`. A prvalue of type
>   `std::nullptr_t` can be converted to a prvalue of type `bool`; the
>   resulting value is `false`.

There is an implicit conversion directly from bare pointer to boolean; so the compiler picks that as the second step because it allows the desired result (conversion to boolean) to be immediately reached.

Comment: Okay, it is *one way to do that*, but why is exactly this way used?

Comment: @sharptooth: Edited and improved, now with more standardese.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

`if( buffer )` means: check if `buffer` is not `NULL`. An array variable points to the start of the array (unless you move it) and is equivalent to a pointer.

The optimization just returns 1 because that `buffer` is allocated on the stack, so it definitely has a value (pointer to the location on the stack), so it's always true.

Comment: An array is not equivalent to a pointer; it's a separate type, convertible to a pointer if required.

Answer (score 0):

You said it yourself :

> buffer decays to a pointer

Since the array is on the stack, it can not be NULL (unless something goes wrong, like stack smashing).